# npm "This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date." You must update to v4.9.2 or newer

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to add aws-amplify & aws-amplify-react modules to my app.

When I run:

**npm install --save aws-amplify aws-amplify-reac**

I received a bunch a WARN messages for missing and deprecated dependencies, which I was able to take care of, except this one:

[image]

I ran **npm i buffer** to install the latest version, but even after that I am still getting the same error message when installing aws-amplify & aws-amplify-react.

**npm list buffer** shows:

[image]

What can I do to take care of this message?

Comment: I'm having the same error with Angular 10. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: I haven’t found the solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Try removing NPM Cache by using the following command:

`npm cache clean --force`

but be careful when using the `--force` flag